# bool find function did not search in array

Tags: c++

I want to make find function for my class that searches an array of items and return 1 if it is found and return 0 otherwise.

Here my code but always returns 0:

```
// implementation file 
bool bag::find(string item_name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if (arr[i] == item_name)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

string arr[5]={"a","b","c","d","e"}

max size of array is 5

```
// main
cout << find("a");
```

How I can make it search correctly?

Comment: Show us the `arr` array.

Comment: `bag::find` looks like a member function, whereas invocation in main looks like invocation of global?

Comment: What type is arr. Code is  right

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker `bag` could be a namespace. :P

Comment: @not-rightfold, theoretically ;)

Comment: All in all, showing the complete real (non)working could be useful.

Comment: Without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), we cannot help you.

Comment: Is `arr` a C style array or vector?

Comment: there must be something wrong in the parts of your code that are not shown here. [This](http://pastebin.com/9CPM4u3W) simple, ugly test of your code prints 1

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::find`:

```
bool bag::find(std::string item)
{
    return std::find(arr, arr + 5, item) != &arr[5];
}
```

I'm assuming `arr` is a C-style array until you say otherwise.

Comment: Though not deserving a downvote, I don't think it's a good answer. It doesn't involve understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you defined your array as having element type char then indeed your function will not work because an object of type char can not be implicitly converted to type std::string.